# Reference an unknown value to autopopulate new rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a solution when a user inserts a new row in a list, that will be referenced to automatically populate multiple rows in a separate list. The part on the right should autopopulate as users add additional rows on the left (e.g. asset numbers). Additionally, the asset attribute and asset value are repeating and the same for each new asset number. Any thoughts? [Before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTbT4.png)

(This is my first question so hopefully I'm doing it right! Thanks for your understanding and patience!)

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) event. It will run any code placed within it when a change is made in a worksheet. You can specify within that function to only update a certain range(s) on the right when a change occurs within a certain range on the left.

Answer (score 0):

In the sheet containing the data (here it is sheet called Target - change as appropriate) have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not IsEmpty(Target) And Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Target")

        Dim lastSourceRow As Long
        Dim lastTargetRow As Long

        lastSourceRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        NextTargetRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        With ws.Cells(NextTargetRow, "D")

            .Resize(3, 1).Value = ws.Cells(lastSourceRow, "A")
            .Offset(, 1) = "Blue"
            .Offset(, 2) = "45"
            .Offset(1, 1) = "Big"
            .Offset(1, 2) = "20"
            .Offset(2, 1) = "Cold"
            .Offset(2, 2) = "5"

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```